# parameterless public constructor - Unity

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, dependency-injection

I got this problem with the Controller:
 An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type '*.WebMvc.Controllers.HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

```
 public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    #region Fields
    private readonly INewsService _newsService;
    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public HomeController(INewsService newsService)
    {
        this._newsService = newsService;
    }

    #endregion

    #region unilities
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }
    #endregion

}


 public interface INewsService : IEntityService<proNew>
{
    proNew GetById(int Id);
}


  public interface IEntityService<T> : IService  where T : class 
{
    void Create(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    void Update(T entity);
}

public abstract class EntityService<T> : IEntityService<T> where T : class 
{
    IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    IGenericRepository<T> _repository;
    public EntityService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IGenericRepository<T> repository)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _repository = repository;
    }
    public virtual void Create(T entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
        }
        _repository.Add(entity);
        _unitOfWork.Commit();
    }
    public virtual void Update(T entity)
    {
        if (entity == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
        _repository.Edit(entity);
        _unitOfWork.Commit();
    }
    public virtual void Delete(T entity)
    {
        if (entity == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
        _repository.Delete(entity);
        _unitOfWork.Commit();
    }
    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _repository.GetAll();
    }
}


 public class NewsService : EntityService<proNew>, INewsService
{
    IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    INewsRepository _countryRepository;

    public NewsService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, INewsRepository newsRepository) : base(unitOfWork, newsRepository)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _countryRepository = newsRepository;
    }

    public proNew GetById(int Id)
    {
        return _countryRepository.GetById(Id);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using dependency injection here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Unity for dependency injection and want it to resolve dependencies for you, check out [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection). It has a complete recipe for your scenario.

To sum up, you have to set Unity as your dependency resolver and then configure types that expose interfaces required by your controllers.